# Ag-grid auto save after adding a new row

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm working for a requirement(Angular 4) which is.. when user will click on insert data button and fill all the mandatory fields and click on another row or unfocused the current row. Then new data should be automatically saved(Save function should be called). Please help me.

I'm trying to call the onSave() function when user click on another row (not in same row another cell, it should be another cell in another row). But rowValueChanged is not working.

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="myGrid" class="ag-theme-dark" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [columnTypes]="columnTypes" [rowData]="rowData" (rowValueChanged)= "onRowValueChanged($event)" [enableSorting]="true" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" > </ag-grid-angular>` function declaration in .ts file: onRowValueChanged(params: any){ this.onSave(); }
```

Thanks in advance.